# What is the reason that OpenAI implements complex context management in ChatGPT but does not use it for their API?

Tags: open-ai, chatgpt, vector-space

According to this discussion

[How does ChatGPT retain the context of previous questions?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/38150/how-does-chatgpt-retain-the-context-of-previous-questions)

it is clear that OpenAI already has implemented some serious engineer to ensure that the ChatGPT experience is a great one by enabling ChatGPT to have very good context management. In order words, ChatGPT can recall things long past it's token limit (much earlier in the conversation).

However, this function does not exists in the API. Why is that? I know we that we cannot know for sure what the proprietary reasons are, but what are some good theories?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a question about a company's policy.